# buttons inside scroll view dosen't work on click - android

Tags: android, button, touch, scrollview, block

I have this xml structure for main activity

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <ScrollView>
        <RelativeLayout>
            <TextView />    
            <ImageView />
            <RelativeLayout>
                <Button />
                <Button />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout>
    <ScrollView>
        <RelativeLayout>
            <TextView />    
            <ImageView />
            <RelativeLayout>
                <Button />
                <Button />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The scroll views have one child i.e. relative layout, still, the buttons inside that don't work.
How to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance

Comment: give details about any error that on button click  happen.and according to your code you are using starting tag with Small 'r' but close tag with capital 'R' </RelativeLayout> see in your code that may be error gererate code.

Comment: case sensitivity is not the issue, Code is all fine. Here, I've entered it wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

Can u attach the error log. ?

because when i have tried button click inside scroll view(used single scroll view) its working fine.

Comment: Yeah it works if i use the Scroll view above the main relative layout. I am trying to use two scroll views inside a relative layout with each containing relative layout as child. And i couldn't find any error message shown in logs as buttons onClick event is not being called. ScrollView is blocking click events...